# What's the default KeepAlive value for a TCP socket in a UNIX-like Docker container?

Tags: docker, tcp, socket

I am creating a TCP socket as follows:

```
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, 
                     SocketType.Stream,
                     ProtocolType.Tcp);
if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
    _socket.ConfigureKeepAlive(true, 5000, 1000);
```

As I'm working with Docker containers, that `ConfigureKeepAlive()` is not executed, but this also means that I have no idea for how long my socket will remain open. When viewing the source code of that `ConfigureKeepAlive()` I see something like this:

```
socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.KeepAliveValues, keepAliveValues, null);
```

I don't understand this piece of code. Can anybody explain me what are the default KeepAlive values of a TCP socket and how I can read that from the `_socket` variable?

Thanks in advance

Ps1.: For your information, hereby the platform information:

```
Environment.OSVersion    {Unix 5.10.102.1}  System.OperatingSystem
```

**Edit:** Ps2.: For your information, hereby some information on the corresponding Docker container:

```
# uname -a
Linux 0be4318feadd 5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Wed Mar 2 00:30:59 UTC 2022 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# cd /proc/sys/net/ipv4
# cat tcp_keepalive_time
7200
# cat tcp_keepalive_probes
9
# cat tcp_keepalive_intvl
75
```

Why does the Docker container seems to break the connection after ±5 minutes while `tcp_keepalive_time` equals two entire hours?

Comment: Assuming that this is in the context of your other questions regarding close of a socket by an application: TCP keepalive is not about closing idle connections or similar. It is only to early detect if a connection is broken (packet transfer fails) even if the connection is idle (i.e. nothing to transfer). TCP keepalive is completely unrelated to HTTP keepalive and while similar in name these are totally different concepts. An application will only close a connection because of TCP keepalive if the connection is already broken.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Glad to see you here :-) So the "KeepAlive" has nothing to do with the socket being closed, and my StackOverflow might be more relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877611 ?

Comment: If your are talking about HTTP/HTTPS connections (which is not clear) then there is the concept of HTTP keepalive. Simply it says that one can have more than one HTTP request over the same connection. But, support for HTTP keepalive only says that one MIGHT do this. Both client and server are allowed to close an idle connection (i.e. no response outstanding) at any time they want. Assuming that with HTTP keepalive the connection must be kept open by the peer is wrong.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: I'm sorry this is not clear: I'm not dealing with HTTP but purely with TCP sockets.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: As you stated correctly, the platform's "KeepAlive" options seem unrelated to the TCP sockets being closed after more or less five minutes. Do you have an idea what might be the reason of this closure?

Comment: *"Do you have an idea what might be the reason of this closure?"* - the only information here is "TCP" and "closes unexpectedly [for you]". This is is not sufficient information to narrow down the cause. It can be that the application is designed this way. It can be a bug. It can be that your client behaves wrong and thus the peer closes the connection. And probably more reasons

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: My application opens a TCP socket, and I don't see any "timeout"-like parameter being used. I know for sure that it's my computer, sending the TCP FIN message. It seems to happen after ±5 minutes (but this is difficult to be sure). My computer regularly works with TCP sockets, who remain open for more than 5 minutes, so I believe it has something to do with application. My application is a Docker-based solution, so I wonder if the problem should be searched for in the containers of the Docker application, which are Linux-like. I hope this clarifies the situation?

Comment: *"I hope this clarifies the situation?"* - not much. If you know that the FIN is first send by your application then it must some behavior of your application. What causes this behavior (as defined by protocol, setting, bug) is still unknown. There is no generic behavior here which is independent of protocol and applications.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: That's the whole problem with Docker: it's an application, which consists of so-called "containers" who are like virtual machines, so this makes it very difficult to determine if it's an applicationlike or a platformlike behaviour. I already asked another question on StackOverflow on how to determine which Docker container is responsible for which behviour, but also no luck there: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74877611".

Answer (score 0):

The default depends on your operating system.

To my knowledge, most operating systems have keepalive disabled by default, that corresponds to a value of zero.

You would normally enable keepalives only if you expect that the connection will be long-lived, and will have long quiet periods, and the connection might break if no packets are sent (e.g. because of a stateful firewall or an on-demand connection).

Comment: Do you know where I can find the `KeepAlive` values? I have a Windows-10 computer, I'm launching a group of Docker containers, which are all UNIX-like.

Comment: Normally this is set per socket, as it is required only for a few applications. SSH has a configuration setting that makes it set the keepalive option on its own sockets, because shells that remain idle for a long time are one of the more obvious examples where you might want keepalives.